# How can I transfer primary to the button.tsx component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

[image]

How can I transfer primary to the button.tsx component, and then from it in the button style.ts and there to use it for the stylization condition.

It is necessary to make two buttons of different colors from the button component.
[image]

Comment: You should not post code as Image. You should past your code into your question and then click `{}` button in the toolbar or press `Ctrl` + `K`

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as screenshot(s)? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At `Button` component, you should pass `primary` to `TextButton`.

```
const Button : FC<ChildrenType> = ({primary, children}) => {
  return (
    <MainButton>
      <TextButton primary={primary}>{children}</TextButton>
    </MainButton>
  );
}
```